# Assigment expression

Tags: c++

Will be Assigment operator (`=`) return the value of the left (or right part)?

```
QVector<function>::Iterator it;

binOp *bpl = nullptr;
                    
bool b1 = (bpl = dynamic_cast<binOp *>(&*(it-2))) != nullptr;
```

So, i have my own class (binOp : function), and i try use dynamic_cast into expression. If i will use assignment to `bpl`, does it will be equals to `bpl` and same like this?:

```
bpl = dynamic_cast<binOp *>(&*(it-2)));

bool b2 = bpl != nullptr;
```

So will be b1 equals b2?

Comment: after `=` has been executed it shouldnt matter if you compare to the lhs or rhs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`=` assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment) returns *a reference* to the left-hand operand.  So, your 1st example will work just fine, and the result will be equivalent to your 2nd example.